# What does "大开大合" mean?

Tags: meaning

I checked [this](http://tw.18dao.net/%E6%88%90%E8%AA%9E%E8%A9%9E%E5%85%B8/%E5%A4%A7%E9%96%8B%E5%A4%A7%E5%90%88) out, but I couldn't really understand the meaning behind it.

> 形容文思跌盪，放得開，收得攏。

Does it mean good introduction, and good conclusion or something similar?

Comment: iciba:
文思：the thread of ideas in writing ； the train of thought in writing ； the flow of thoughts and ideas in writing
跌蕩／跌荡：be bold and unconstrained，
放得開／放得开：open - minded，（see examples)
收得攏／收得拢：收拢 gather together,draw in, furl,round up, 收得拢 could mean "gathered together, concentrated"

Comment: Please provide context. It could be used in different situations. To better understand it and its usage, you can just go to baidu.com and search it.

Comment: I think it means 收放自如，which is more commonly used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that the usage of every word is in the person's control. Having an outstanding command of the language, the person knows where to conclude the article and how to put all of the inspirations in. In addition, the person also has a lot of ideas, making the person usually write a lot in a short period of time (also in good quality). As a native speaker, this is my interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

As a native Chinese speaker, I'd say "大开大合" is used to describe something (for instance, a novel/play/movie) that is epic, or grand in scale.

Answer (score 0):

if I want to fly high, I can get to the top of sky, meanwhile if I want to go deep, I can get to the kernel of the earth. This could be called 大开大合

you see?